# Problem with WIFI and multicast

Tags: networking, wifi, multicast, upnp

Hi All
I ve two PC's **A** and **B** which are connected to **LAN1** .A is listening on UPNP multicast address 239.255.255.250 .
I have a mobile device **D** which is connected to a WIFI and the **WIFI** is connected to LAN1 .
Ip address of PC A is xxx.yyy.209.80 PC B is xxx.yyy.209.81 and device D is xxx.yyy.209.82.
If I send a multicast packet to 239.255.255.250 from PC B it reaches PC A.
But if I send a multicast pakcet from device D it **never** reaches PC A .Can anyone tell me why ?How to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance
Kozlov

Comment: Provide some details about the WiFi bridge please, although easiest is just test another machine on the WiFi network.

Comment: Am afraid i cant get those details .Anyways will try once more.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is 3 years old but the following information may be useful to someone. I have an iPhone App that uses a 239.x.x.x address and I have issues with certain wireless access points. I found a document that says the following:

> There are some special multicast groups, say "well known multicast
>   groups", you should not use in your particular applications due the
>   special purpose they are destined to:
>
> 224.0.0.1 is the all-hosts group. If you ping that group, all multicast capable hosts on the network should answer, as every
>   multicast capable host must join that group at start-up on all it's
>   multicast capable interfaces.
>   224.0.0.2 is the all-routers group. All multicast routers must join that group on all it's multicast capable interfaces.
>   224.0.0.4 is the all DVMRP routers, 224.0.0.5 the all OSPF routers, 224.0.013 the all PIM routers, etc. All this special multicast groups are regularly published in the "Assigned Numbers" RFC.
>
> In any case, range 224.0.0.0 through 224.0.0.255 is reserved for local
>   purposes (as administrative and maintenance tasks) and datagrams
>   destined to them are never forwarded by multicast routers. Similarly,
>   the range 239.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 has been reserved for
>   "administrative scoping" (see section 2.3.1 for information on
>   administrative scoping).

Anyway I changed my address to 238.x.x.x and that did not help with the Netgear R6100 AP. The issue I have seen with Wireshark is that LAN packets are not forwarded to wireless devices. I have not tried the other direction.